# Property Grid > how to refresh the main property

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

[image]

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BrokerageConverter))]
[DescriptionAttribute("Brokerage Details")]
[PropertyGridInitialExpanded(true)]
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
public class Brokerage
{
    private Decimal _Amt = Decimal.Zero; private string _currency = "";

    public Brokerage() { }
    public Brokerage(Decimal broAmount, string broCurrency) { Amount = broAmount; Currency = broCurrency; }

    [ReadOnly(false)]
    public Decimal Amount 
    {
        get { return _Amt; }
        set { _Amt = value; }
    }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Currency
    {
        get { return _currency; }
        set { _currency = value; }
    }

    //public override string ToString() { return _Amt.ToString() + " - " + _currency; }
}

public class BrokerageConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(Brokerage))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }


    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type t)
    {
        if (t == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, t);
    }

    // Overrides the ConvertFrom method of TypeConverter.
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string[] v = ((string)value).Split(new char[] { '-' });
            return new Brokerage(Decimal.Parse(v[0]), v[1]);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    // Overrides the ConvertTo method of TypeConverter.
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(System.String) && value is Brokerage)
        {
            Brokerage b = (Brokerage)value;
            return b.Amount.ToString() + " - " + b.Currency.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Now when I change the Amount, the Buyer Bro is not updating automatically. How to achieve it? Let me know, if i have to provide some additional info

Answer (score 4):

Adding the attribute "[NotifyParentProperty(true)]" will do the trick:

```
[ReadOnly(false)]
[NotifyParentProperty(true)]
public Decimal Amount 
{
    get { return _Amt; }
    set { _Amt = value; }
}
```

Make sure to add

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Now when you change Amount and loose the focus of this distinct property,
the parent property will automatically be updated.
Cheers!

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Just added it to the property that is being updated and voila, thanks.

Comment: That works great. I wish the rest of the related articles had this. Now... Do you have one for starting a property of complex type using ExpandableObjectConverter that expands the node automatically?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in the past.

I did put `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]` or `RefreshProperties.All`, then I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my target objects, but I never managed to get the automatic mechanism it to work correctly.

Apparently, I [am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120496/updating-a-propertygrid/4955653#4955653) [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411869/control-is-not-refresh-when-custom-type-property-is-changed).

I ended using the `.Refresh()` method on the PropertyGrid. Now it works all the time.

```
var b = new Brokerage(10, "EUR");
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = b;

...

b.Amount = 20;
this.propertyGrid1.Refresh();
```

Comment: The property grid doesn't use INotifyPropertyChanged at all. Also, RefreshProperties is for when the properties are modified through the propertygrid itself, not from outside. I don't think there is any automatic way. Maybe if the object implements IComponent, but this may be complex/overkill.

Comment: The property grid is tricky as hell. I wish I had some time to decompile it and see what is behind the curtain.

Comment: My PG knowledge comes from having past hours in Reflector on it, but its code is huge...

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding,

```
[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint)]
```

to the 2 properties inside your Brokerage class?